# Combining jQuery datepicker functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have two functions that I'd like to use to narrow down the selection in my jQuery Datepicker. I'm stuck on how to combine these two functions so I can use them in combination with each other. Right now which ever one I put first takes priority and the other doesn't work.

```
//the html
<input type="text" class="input-text  hasDatepicker" name="order_delivery_date" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select Date" value="">     


//two functions, whichever one is first works
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(function ($) { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+1", maxDate: "+1M +10D" }); });
        jQuery(function ($) { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() != 2, '']; }})});
    </script>


// my attempt to combine them, not working
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(function ($) { 
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+1", maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() != 2, '']; }}); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Details...

Comment: one function limits a day of the week from being chosen, in this case it is the 2nd day or Tuesdays. The other function sets a min/max date range. I know they don't work together because when the min/max function is first I can still choose Tuesdays and when the no Tuesdays function is first I can choose any date without a mix/max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of code already creates a datepicker object on `$('#datepicker')` DOM element.
You should pass all options to the datepicker all in one go:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: "+1", maxDate: "+1M +10D" , beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() != 2, '']; }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$('#datepicker').data("DateTimePicker").beforeShowDay = function(date){ 
                                           return [date.getDay() != 2, ''];
                                        };`

instead of the second `.datepicker()`.